# Can't use keystoreRelativeTo path in ManagementFraction of Wildfly swarm

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, swarm

I have problem with keystoreRelativeTo option in ManagementFraction of Wildfly swarm app.

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
        Swarm swarm = new Swarm(args);
        Archive<JAXRSArchive> archive = createJaxRsArchive();       
        swarm
            .fraction(createManagementFraction())
            .fraction(createUndertowFraction())
            .fraction(createSecurityFraction())
            .start()
            .deploy(archive);
    }


ManagementFraction managementFraction = new ManagementFraction().securityRealm("UndertowRealm", (realm) -> {
    realm.truststoreAuthentication((authn) -> { authn
        //.keystoreRelativeTo("/certs")
        .keystorePath("sometruststore.jks")             
        .keystorePassword("pass");
    });
    realm.sslServerIdentity(new SslServerIdentity<>()
        //.keystoreRelativeTo("/certs")
        .keystorePath("somekeystore.jks")           
        .keystorePassword("pass")
        .alias("x")
        .keyPassword("pass")
            );
});     
return managementFraction;
```

}

Without ".keystoreRelativeTo("/certs")" it works fine as long as *.jks files are in projects root dir. With option ".keystoreRelativeTo("/certs")" I would expect so it checks for jks files inside projectRootDir/certs, but it's not. I've tried also with an absolute path for example C:/certs but doesn't work as well. 
I've got error:

> 2017-01-03 21:56:26,638 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
>       ("subsystem" => "undertow"),
>       ("server" => "default-server"),
>       ("https-listener" => "https")
>   ]) - failure description: {
>       "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined,
>       "WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
>           "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.undertow.listener.https"],
>           "Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.server.path./certs/"]
>       }
>   }
>
> 2017-01-03 21:56:26,639 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
>       ("core-service" => "management"),
>       ("security-realm" => "UndertowRealm") ]) - failure description: {
>       "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.server.path./certs/"],
>       "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
>           "jboss.server.controller.management.security_realm.UndertowRealm.trust-manager is missing [jboss.server.path./certs/]",
>           "jboss.server.controller.management.security_realm.UndertowRealm.key-manager is missing [jboss.server.path./certs/]"
>       ] }

I dont know what "jboss.server.path" is, I thought it is some jboss properties but can't find nor set it. I've tried also with jboss.server.config.dir parameter (setting it before to /certs/ or C:/certs/):
 .keystoreRelativeTo("jboss.server.config.dir")

but error message is the same: (...) "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.undertow.listener.https"],
        "Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.server.path.\"jboss.server.config.dir\""] (...)

Is it some bug? Any help would be appreciated.